# How much my reputation increased exactly?

Tags: discussion

Today when I opened SO, there was a +3 reputation increase notification and when clicked on it, I saw this:

[image]

Why is it like this? Why the difference in the numbers?

Comment: Likely you had a -2 from a deleted post that you edited or a post of yours that had the right combination of up and downvotes that had a net rep gain of +2 (e.g question with 2 upvotes, 4 downvotes).  Those actions won't show up as a notification.